# reactjs chrome extension message passing not working

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a hello world chrome extension using a template build from [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

I was able to create the chrome extension by adding a manifest:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Demo React-Chrome extension",
  "description": "This extension shows how to run a React app as a Chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
      "debugger",
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "background",
      "https://*/",
      "http://*/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
      "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  }
}
```

`background.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  console.log(message);
  switch(message.action){
    case "popupOpen":{
      console.log('popup is open');
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
      });
    }
      break;

  }

});
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {showHeader: true};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "popupOpen"}).bind(this);

  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      showHeader: !prevState.showHeader
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          {this.state.showHeader && <h2>Welcome to React Jon</h2>}
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {this.state.showHeader ? "HIDE" : "SHOW"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

However, when I run `npm run build`, I get this error:

> /dev/hello-world/src/App.js   11:5  error  'chrome' is not defined 
>   no-undef
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

How do I call chrome.runtime or pass a message from a react app to background.js?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This error is from [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef), you could add the following line at the top of the file.

```
/*global chrome*/
```

Comment: Awesome.  To be clear, I added it to the top of App.js file, and it worked.

Comment: This will head to another ESLint error(spaced-comment) if there's no space/tab after `/*`.... It should be something like `/* global chrome */`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the error is caused by a compile error from `create-react-app`. It does not allow builds to have `ES Lint` errors in them.

The accepted answer is great, and you can also add comments in this manner (this ES Lint rule is called `no-undef`):

```
/* eslint-disable-rule no-undef */
chrome.blah()
/* eslint-enable-rule no-undef */
```

I have this VS Code extension that I picked up a long the way, and it's amazing:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drKnoxy.eslint-disable-snippets

I recommend it because it's easy to remember to type `esl` and choose from the snippets, far easier than remembering the various ways you can disable rules.